# Select node with specific value

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I was given a web service that I have to use to pull data into a table. Right now it pulls all nodes, but I would like to pull only the nodes with Web.

Searching the web, I can only find examples of how to do this if there is an attribute, which there is not. This is what I have so far, and can't seem to figure out what to do next -

```
XmlNodeList records = root.SelectNodes("descendant::record[//@Origin=Web]");
```

Also tried -

```
XmlNodeList records = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/Results/Record/Origin['=Web']");
```

Edit - I'm aware that neither of the above attempts are even remotely close to working

Edit 2 - XML is set up like this -

```
<results>
  <record>
    <name></name>
    <email></email>
    <origin></origin>
  </record>
</results>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with this XPath:

```
//origin[text()="web"]
```

It means select all `origin` elements (regardless of hierarchy) where the inner text is `web`.

So, your statement becomes now:

```
XmlNodeList records = xmldoc.SelectNodes("//origin[text()='web']");
```

Comment: Which of the above examples should I use this with?

Comment: Unfortunately that's exactly what I had, and it's not working for some reason. Not sure if this makes a difference, but I looking at the web service, it shows the origin like this -

    <origin><![CDATA[Web]]></origin>

Would this change the answer?

Comment: @user3869708: OK, so the actual problem is that you have no `origin` elements that contain `web`?

Comment: Apparently not, I now see that it is displayed as <![CDATA[Web]]>

Comment: is there a different route to take?

Comment: @user3869708: No, it's a character casing issue. If you replace `web` with `Web` in the XPath it will work.

Comment: I already had changed that myself, because I figured it was case sensitive. I'm thinking I might be placing the code in the wrong place? I have this `
  xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmldoc.LoadXml(tdata);
                XmlNodeList records = xmldoc.SelectNodes("//origin[text()='Web']");
                records = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("record");
                foreach (XmlNode rec in records)`

Comment: @user3869708: But you're overwriting the records variable... First you get it from SelectNodes and then from  GetElementsByTagName. I tested this on my machine so it works fine.

Comment: I had a feeling that was an issue, so I removed the line with GetElementsByTagName, and now I when I try to run it I don't get anything

Comment: @user3869708: The issue must be somewhere else, because this works. Put a breakpoint on the line with SelectNodes and check the records variable right after SelectNodes is called. If the length is 0, then most likely the XML does not contain any matching records.

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time I've had to use something like this, so I'm not entirely sure what breakpoints do.

Comment: @user3869708: It will stop the execution flow at the line the breakpoint is set and you will be able to inspect context variables. Press F9 on the line you want the breakpoint activated.

Comment: And when you say "if the length is 0..." you mean?

Comment: I'm honestly not even sure what you did to get that little drop down to show up.

Comment: @user3869708: hover over the variable. Or select it and press ctrl-alt-q.

Comment: Hovering or ctrl-alt-q both did nothing on "records"

Comment: I have a catch to display "No Data" when no data can be pulled, which it currently does display. I'm just unsure as to why nothing can be pulled, when I know for a fact there is data that fits the criteria.

Comment: @user3869708: You should isolate the issue first, that's why I suggested to debug the records var and make sure there's something in it. Now you can't be sure where the problem lies. It can be there or after that. Put the breakpoint back and when it hits go to Debug/Windows and select Autos. In the autos tool window you will be able to see the record variable.

Comment: Debug > Windows has no "Autos". I have "output" and "immediate".

Comment: @user3869708: It will show up there after the breakpoint is hit (while the program is running). :)

Comment: @merceln it seems the breakpoint is being hit with something called iisexpress.exe? No idea what that means.

Comment: @user3869708: It means that you're working on an web app. IIS Express is the web server.

Comment: Also, I believe the breakpoint was hit, but I still have no 'autos' in debug > windows